# How do I disable autocomplete

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

How do I disable the autocomplete in my lightning components. I want the `ui:inputText` and `ui:inputSecret` not to autocomplete the fields. But I am struggling in doing this.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="slds-form" >
<div class="slds-form-element inputwidth slds-m-vertical--medium"  
        <div class="slds-p-top--medium" >       
            <div class="sfdc slds-has-divider--bottom">

                <ui:inputText  value="" aura:id="username" keyup="{!c.onKeyUp}" class="input border sfdc_usernameinput sfdc" label="{!v.usernameLabel}" />
            </div>
            <div class="sfdc">
                <div class="slds-form-element inputwidth slds-m-vertical--medium">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control" >
                        <label><p>Password</p></label>
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-has-divider--bottom slds-theme--default">
                            <ui:inputSecret value="{!v.password}" aura:id="inputPasswordSecret" keyup="{!c.onKeyUp}" class="border input sfdc_passwordinput slds-show sfdc" />
                            <ui:inputText value="{!v.password}" aura:id="inputPasswordText" keyup="{!c.onKeyUp}" class="border input sfdc_passwordinput slds-hide sfdc"  />
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="{!c.togglePassword}" onmouseup="{!c.togglePassword}">
                                <lightning:icon iconName="utility:preview" size="small" class="slds-m-horizontal--x-small"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-p-top--xx-large">
                <div class="slds-col slds-p-top--small">
                    <p class="slds-text-align--left">
                        <div>
                            <button class= "slds-button pressed" onclick="{!c.onClickStep2}">
                                Forgot your password?
                            </button>     
                        </div> 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <div class="slds-text-align--right">
                        <lightning:button label="{!v.loginButtonLabel}" variant="brand"  class="sfdc_button" onclick="{!c.handleLogin}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:renderIf>
</div>
```

This is the action in the controller:

```
 handleLogin: function (component, event, helper) {
    helper.handleLogin(component, event, helper);
},

 onKeyUp: function(component, event, helper){

    if (event.getParam('keyCode')===13) {
        helper.handleLogin(component, event, helper);
    }
},
```

this is the action after in the helper:

```
handleLogin: function (component, event, helper) {
var username = component.find("username").get("v.value");
var password = component.find("inputPasswordSecret").get("v.value");
var action = component.get("c.login");
var startUrl = component.get("v.startUrl");
console.log(username);
console.log(password);
startUrl = decodeURIComponent(startUrl);

action.setParams({username:username, password:password, startUrl:startUrl});
action.setCallback(this, function(a){
    var rtnValue = a.getReturnValue();
    if (rtnValue !== null) {
        component.set("v.errorMessage",rtnValue);
        component.set("v.showError",true);
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

},

Comment: Looks like your username and password fields have a Keyup attribute bound to it. Why dont you try removing those keyup events keyup="{!c.onKeyUp}" , maybe they are giving you the auto-completes. If that is not the case .. we request you to share all the components so that we can take a look.

Comment: @Sumuga please see my edits

Comment: The methods that you have mentioned, contains only 1 method handleLogin. It looks like you are referring other methods like "onKeyUp" as well. Could you search for those methods ?

Comment: @Sumuga I added the onKeyUp

Comment: Looks like Your keyUp is looking for an Enter to handle the login. But  these methods dont have the auto-complete logic. By "Auto-complete" what do you mean it is something like you type "Acce" and it comeplete something as "Accept" or is it like the remember username password in browsers ?

Comment: The remember username password in browser part is wat I dont want. Can I turn this off?

Comment: @Ant - Please do not deface your posts by removing the code. If you do not want your code public then don't post it in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Try including your inputs inside of a

```
<form autocomplete="off" > .... </form>
```

Another alternative would be to use javascript in the afterRender/rerender methods to add the autocomplete attribute

component.cmp

```
 <ui:inputText aura:id="anInput" ...otherparams />
```

Render.js

```
afterRender: function(cmp, helper){
    this.superAfterRender();
    //your component will now be rendered and you'll be able to access the input via javascript and set attributes that are not supported by the ui:inputX

    //this will give you the html described here: 
    https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputText.htm
    var theinputdiv = cmp.find('anInput').getElement();

    //next we want to get input element which is a child
    var theInputItself = theInputDiv.childNodes[1];
    //and now turn off autocomplete
    theInputItself.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');

    //more concisely -cmp.find('anInput').getElement().childNodes[1].setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
}
```

Comment: I am pretty new to this and dont completely understand what you mean with the second option. Could you maybe explain it in dummy language? Thanks

Comment: Edited. Let me know if that helps.